# How do I force the language prefix to the current langcode on node with "Not specified" language?

Tags: nodes, i18n-l10n, 9

I have a multilingual site whose default language is Italian. Some of the content has no language defined.

The problem occurs when I browse the site in English. All the links are displayed with the /en prefix, except the links to the untranslated nodes.
In views, the links that are displayed on those nodes don't have a language prefix. As a result, once you arrive on those nodes, the whole site is in the default language because Drupal then redirects to the same content with the prefix /it being the default language.

Is it possible to force a language prefix on these untranslated nodes (with the current language)?

I am using Drupal 9.4.8.